# Need help solving $\int\frac{\sin(x+1)\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)+4} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

As the title says I need help solving the indefinite integral

$$\int\frac{\sin(x+1)\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)+4}dx$$

Thank you for any help.

Comment: have you tried writing sin(x+1) as sin(x)cos(1) + cos(x)sin(1) ?

Comment: Yes I have, it is the later portions of the calculation that I seem to get lost in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$\frac{\sin(x+1)\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)+4} \,dx= \frac{(\sin{x}\cos{1}+\cos{x}\sin{1})\cos(x)}{\sin^2(x)+4} \,dx = \\
 = \cos{1}\frac{\sin{x}\,d(\sin{x})}{\sin^2(x)+4}+ \sin{1}\frac{1-\sin^2{x}}{\sin^2(x)+4}\,dx.$$
Can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

Hint...start by expanding the $\sin(x+1)$ term using the compound angle identity, so thatvyou have two integrals $$\cos1\int\frac{\sin2x}{9-\cos 2x}dx+\sin1\int\frac{1}{1+4\tan^2x}dx$$

The first is immediately apparent, and the second will work out using $t=\tan x$ and application of partial fractions.

Comment: Is the first integral correct though? Is the denominator not supposed to be $9-\cos(2x)$?

Comment: Yes, you are right! Thanks @Matt